# Error with NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I am trying to generate an UIActionSheet from a NSDictionary.

codeCountryMap is NSDictionary variable defined in .h file. The code compiled correctly but crashes on run time. But the whole code works when the initialization is done in the handleEvents method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *codes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"91", @"01", @"002", nil];
    NSArray *cName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ABC", @"QWE", @"XYZ", nil];
    codeCountryMap = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:codes forKeys:cName];
}

-(IBAction) handleEvents:(id)sender
{       
    UIActionSheet *displayCodeCountryMap = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Country" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];

    for(id key in codeCountryMap) {
        [displayCodeCountryMap addButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)key];
    }

    [displayCodeCountryMap addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    displayCodeCountryMap.cancelButtonIndex = [codeCountryMap count];
    displayCodeCountryMap.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [displayCodeCountryMap showInView:self.view];
    [displayCodeCountryMap release];
    [country resignFirstResponder];
}
```

The app crashes when the handleEvents: method is called. 
Any kind of help would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats the error you get? what line does it occur?

Comment: it is a run time error.......... occurs when the handleEvents method is called. I have updated the question as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This more than likely is a memory management issue.  It looks like you are setting the iVar codeCountryMap to an autoreleased object of NSDictionary and not retaining it(at least not in this code snippet).  This means that when the 'handleEvents' method is called the NSDictionary item has been released from memory.

Try either retaining the NSDictionary item or, if codeCountryMap is defined as a retained property, then use the following code to set it.

```
self.codeContryMap = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:codes forKeys:cName];
```

This will use the synthesized methods to set the property and retain it.

Comment: i have already used
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSDictionary codeCountryMap;
to set the reatin property in my .h file and synthesozed the same in .m file.

Comment: Did you change your code to use self.codeCountryMap instead of just codeCountryMap?  When you don't use 'self.[var]' it does not use the property methods to set the variable(you are setting the iVar directly) and therefore it does not get retained.

Comment: thanks a ton got that......it worked.. :).... I will keep this in mind for future...  thnks again

Answer (score 0):

No need for 2 `nil`s terminators in the `otherButtonTitles` argument. If you had passed in strings then it would have to be nil terminated. Since you did not, one `nil` is enough.

```
UIActionSheet *displayCodeCountryMap = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Country" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
```